# Task Queue in GAE JAVA - Battle Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, game-engine, pipeline, task-queue

I use Google App Engine Java for over a year.  Trying write a simple strategy game.
Unfortunately current solution does not satisfy me. My experience with GAE is even insufficient.

My problem is to simulate a battle at a specific time, which shall be calculated in the task queue.

Current solution:

I have entities in Datastore :
BattleInfo ( field: battleID, startTime, userA, userB)

I have prepared two servlets: **BattleInitServlet and BattleServlet.**

**BattleInitServlet** - execute the query to the datastore and loads BattleInfo. Tasks are added to the battle-queue:

```
Queue queue = QueueFactory.getQueue("battle-queue");
    ...
    for(BattleInfo i : list){
        long countdownMillis = i.getStartTime() - currentTime; 
        queue.add(TaskOptions.Builder.withUrl("/battle").param("battleID", i.getBattleID()).method(TaskOptions.Method.POST).countdownMillis(countdownMillis)); 
    }
```

**BattleServlet** - task will start at a specific time. I receive BattleInfo from the battleID and loads the required data. Simulates the battle and save to datastore.

BattleInitServlet is executed every 30 minutes using cron.

With a few simulation , result is OK. Tests with a large amount of simulation,  task queue is clogged. I can solve this by changing the settings Queue, but I increase costs, and does not solve the problem. I do not know how to speed up and optimize.

I tested the pipeline API that works fast. The problem is that the pipeline API initiates a moment and executed tasks immediately .

I want to prepare a pipeline using tasks that runs in the background and executed the battle for a specified time and simulates it. Just don't know how to write it using GAE and tasks.

Has anyone had a similar problem?

Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you link the Pipeline API with your Cron Job to delay execution?

FYI, I guess Pipeline API also leverages Task Queues internally but uses sharding, slicing to optimize the performance.